# use different babel preset when running mocha tests

Tags: npm, mocha.js, babeljs

My npm package build runs with babel and I configured a babel preset in my `package.json` with

`"babel": { "presets": ["es2015"] }`

I also configured a mocha test script with

`"test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register"`

However, I would like to run my tests using a different babel preset than that one specified for my build.

Is it possible? I would you achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a file named `babel-hook.js` and put in it:

```
require("babel-register")({
  presets: [ /* whatever values you want here */ ],
});
```

then run Mocha like this:

```
mocha --require babel-hook
```

This will register Babel and you can use any configuration [option](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babel-register/#specifying-options) you want with it, separate from anything in `package.json`.

Answer (score 7):

Babel [accommodates environment variables](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/#env-option) so you could set a `test` environment variable and alter your presets accordingly:

In your `package.json`:

```
"babel": {
    "env": {
      "test": {
        "presets": [/* your test presets */]
      }
    },
    "presets": [/* your usual presets */]
}
```

Then, run your mocha command like so:

```
"test: BABEL_ENV=test mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register"
```

Comment: Also great. I think that is an even more expressive way. Meaning that when someone looks at `package.json`, it becomes clear what _dependency-on-test-preset_ is used for.

Comment: Just realized that this might not work on Windows because the Windows shell won't understand the environment variable declaration.

Comment: I would think there is some equivalent command in Windows.  Perhaps `SET BABEL_ENV=test` or something like that per the [docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/#env-option)?

Comment: thanks for this, babel.env.test.presets really saved my day

Answer (score 1):

The answer about configuring babel in package.json was partially ok.
I needed to add seperate env entries to make it work cause otherwise the config outside env would always run.
So the final configuration example would look like this:

```
"babel": {
    "env": {
      "test-console": {
        "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
        "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
      }
    ,
      "test": {
        "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
        "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", "transform-remove-console"]
      }
    }
```

And scripts:

```
 "scripts": {
    "test-console-log": "BABEL_ENV=test-console mocha || TRUE",
    "test": "BABEL_ENV=test mocha || TRUE"
  }
```

Comment: thanks for this, "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"] saved me